# Apache Ignite: Cache item lock usage

Tags: thread-safety, locking, atomic, ignite

I need to modify cache items on different threads on JVM so I need to be sure that all items are modified in order and safely. So I thought that it would be ok if thread create or acquire lock with the cache key and release it after the work is finished. Like that:

```
if(this.igniteCache.lock(k).tryLock()){
                try {
                    if(this.igniteCache.containsKey(k)){
                        List value=this.igniteCache.get(k);
                        value.addAll(v);
                        this.igniteCache.put(k, value);
                    }
            } finally{
                this.igniteCache.lock(k).unlock();
            }

        }
```

So my question is: is it wise to create that muck lock items? Is there any significant cost on memory or network side?

Or can you direct me on this if there are any other way?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical use case for `PESSIMISTIC`/`REPEATABLE_READ` transaction. You can refer to `CacheTransactionExample` [1] included in Ignite (see `deposit()` method).

Also see [2] for more information about transactional support in Ignite.

[1] https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CacheTransactionExample.java

[2] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/transactions